# Problem with sqlite firedac table if fieldnames contains '@'

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

If I open a sqlite table (Delphi 12, FireDAC, TFDTable), where column names contains '@' (e.g. '@@ID') then it works at design time but at run time there is an exception "field not found" raised.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you escaping the names by putting them in double quotes?

Comment: If I use TFDQuery with sql-statement and quoted field names, then it works fine. But with the TFDTable I have no chance to quote the fieldnames. I only select the tablename and set active to true. I use TFDTable because I do not know the table structure, so I can't write the SELECT-statement.